# Nested template variable access in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor

I'm a brand new JavaScript guy (currently playing with Meteor) and would love some critique of the following:

The goal:  I've got two collections

1. Buckets
2. Widgets.

I'm displaying a `select` for each bucket, populated with an `option` for each widget.

The goal is simply to mark the appropriate `option` as `selected` if the bucket currently contains that widget.

I wrestled with this a bit and came up with what feels hack-ey

-- I'm explicitly passing the bucket's contents as a Handlebars variable.  I feel like there's a better way, but not sure how to get 'er done.

Is there a way to get access to the parent template instance's context from a nested template instance?  `#each widget` is being called from within `#each bucket` but `this` only gives me access to the child context.

(This works, I'm just trying to learn here).

**HTML:**

```
<template name="choices">
  {{#each bucket}}
    <label for='{{bucket_name}}'>{{bucket_description}}</label>
    <select id='{{bucket_name}}'>
      {{#each widget}}
        <option value="{{widget_name}}" {{selected ../bucket_contains}}>{{widget_description}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  {{/each}} 
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.choices.bucket = function () {
    return Buckets.find({});
  };

  Template.choices.widget = function () {
    return Widgets.find({}); 
  };

  Template.choices.selected = function (parent) {
    return (this.widget_name === parent) ? 'selected' : '';
  };

  Template.choices.events({
    'change select': function (event) {
      Buckets.update({bucket_name: event.target.id}, {$set: {bucket_contains: event.target.value}});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So `bucket_contains` is a property of Buckets and will be the name of a widget if a widget is assigned to a bucket?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at your code for a few weeks now, the problem is both that there is not a lot to review and there's nothing wrong with it.

Do consider using lowerCamelCasing which is the standard in JS, so `bucket_name` -> `bucketName`.

The code seems elegant enough to me.